# How can I close comments on a mass scale?

Tags: mysql, comments

Having just relaunched a site containing a decade of content, I'd like to close comments on everything over a couple years old.

I thought there was something built in, but either it's not there or I can't find it.

Is there an add-on? Or a simple sequel statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a setting under **Admin → Channel Administration → Channels → Edit Preferences** - under the **Comment Posting Preferences** header - for **Comment Expiration**.

Set a number of days there, and tick the box for "Update all existing comments with this setting" (which should more accurately read "existing *entries*").

[image: Screenshot of setting]

To be clear this won't close all *comments*, but remove the *ability to comment* on all entries which fit the criteria. (Your question uses the phrase "close comments" but I'm pretty sure you don't actually want to *remove* the old comments?)

Comment: You're right, this is what I was after. Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Given that the control panel for comments (Add-ons > Modules > Comments) is a little limited in its date filtering, and if you have lots and lots of comments it would be a chore, a query is probably the best route.

A query that would **close all comment entries** before Sat, 01 Jan 2011 00:00:00 GMT:

```
UPDATE exp_comments
SET status = 'c'
WHERE comment_date < 1293840000
```

OR...If what you meant was to **not *allow* new comments** on entries older than two years then here is a query to do that ([*or just see @Derek's answer!*](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5548/22)):

```
UPDATE exp_channel_titles
SET allow_comments = 'n'
WHERE entry_date < 1293840000
```

You can use [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) to get a Unix timestamp for your comment cut-off date.